# Add style to zxing barcode scanner (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, themes, zxing, phonegap-plugins

I am building an Android app using phoneGap and I have successfully added the [BarcodeScanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner) which uses zxine as the scanner.  I should note that this is my first Android app, so im still getting used to the dev environment.

I would like to style the "scan" screen to look a little more like my app.  For example, change the background color, opacity, add an image, etc.  Does anyone have any idea where to start.

Comment: I found a few of the valus (viewfinder_frame, viewfinder_laser, viewfinder_mask) after looking through the plugin files.  located in /res/values/colors.xml Now how do I add an image to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few of the values (viewfinder_frame, viewfinder_laser, viewfinder_mask) after looking through the plugin files. located in /res/values/colors.xml

Answer (score -1):

You would need to modify the LibraryProject part of the plugin to visually look the way you want it to.